# Unable to push to forked repo using git commit and push using a script

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I have forked a repository on GitHub and clone the forked repository to my local with following **`.git/config`** :

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:namannigam/commons-io.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "upstream"]
        url = git@github.com:apache/commons-io.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

---

Now that I have a script formulated(indented for question readability) for such repositories to be in sync with the upstream and pushing my latest code to the server (my forked branch) with something like this :

```
cd $d # traverse directory
&& git checkout master # checkout the master branch of my fork
&& git fetch -a # fetch all the branches
&& git fetch upstream # https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ 
&& git pull upstream master
&& git merge upstream/master
&& git commit -am "`date`" #commit the current code 
&& git push origin master #push the code to the master of my fork
```

The challenge that I am facing is that the push to my origin/master doesn't succeed with the above script. On the other hand, if I execute all the commands sequentially on the command prompt it works.

---

What I noticed was that the *combination of commit and push is making it difficult* for me to execute the script since the behavior is same as when executing the following separately on the command line from project directory :

```
git commit -am "`date`" && git push origin master  #results into no push
```

---

If in case it may matter:

```
git --version => 2.16.1
```

---

On-demand sample logs against the above script commands for one of the projects :

> ```
> Already on 'master'
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
> remote: Counting objects: 350, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (120/120), done.
> ...
> From github.com:dropwizard/dropwizard
>    4db822962..3f9cf2253  master     -> upstream/master
>  * [new tag]             v1.3.0-rc5 -> v1.3.0-rc5
> From github.com:dropwizard/dropwizard
>  * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
> Updating 4db822962..3f9cf2253
> Fast-forward
>  docs/pom.xml                                                 |  2 +-
>  .... # list of files wiht lines changed
> ++++++++++-----------
>  49 files changed, 147 insertions(+), 116 deletions(-)
> Already up to date.
> On branch master
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 21 commits.
>   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

Comment: It's worth noting that git commits already contain timestamps, so using the output of `date` as a commit message is a strange thing to do.

It would be helpful if you'd paste some output so we have some hope of telling you what's going on, too.

Comment: @ChrisKitching thanks for pitching in, I am aware of the timestamp, just putting the commit message as a dynamic variable for now. On the other hand, the current projects that I have forked are now up to date manually. I would have to wait some time for one of them to lead ahead and then would come back with the exact logs of the script execution. Though in general, the logs would read something like ***Your branch is 139 commits ahead of origin/master.<next-line> nothing to commit, <next-line> <nothing(no push)>***

Answer (score 0):

`git commit` returns `1` if nothing was committed and subsequent chain after `&&` operator is not executed (because it requires success aka `0`).

Try `;` instead of `&&` when joining last `git push`